# FFmpeg Media Source Extension Examples and Adaptive VOD and Live Streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I have a quick questions. Has anybody examples or links for the use of FFmpeg with the Media Source Extension for pure JavaScript adaptive VOD-, or Live-Streaming? I mean really pure not HLS or DASH.

I prefer the chunkless, so say inline-container-segmenting:). So that i have a full files like so:

- video_1080p_5000k.webm
- video_720p_5000k.webm
- video_480p_5000k.webm
- audio_128k.opus
- audio_256k.opus
- and so on ...

What I search are JavaScript snippets and FFmpeg examples for a pure mse-js-adaptive-vod-player;).

Thx

Edit: A deeper explain why i not use DASH or HLS? I try to understand the deeper functions that JavaScript chunk the Videos on the fly, to prevent and memory low error and make a very simple and basic adaptive streaming.

I can load small Videos and Music files into a blob/string. Cool thing but when I try to use the chunking functions I have many problems with some things. That is why I search compact FFmpeg encoder params and JavaScript examples preferably links to sites with that preferably for all free codecs that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Chunkless and Adaptive is a contradiction. You can concatenate chunks, and request with a byte range however. Both HLS and DASH support that mode.

Comment: Hello, okay my question ist then how can i made video files with concatenate chunks with ffmpeg and how can i use this with javascript/mse/video-tag or knows anybody a site with examples. But i mean a pure JavaScript/MSE-Solution without HLS or DASH. Why HLS is not free and Dash is the answer but i specially want to use MSE without ready standards. I know No Dash without MSE and when MSE why not Dash;), but i'm intrested in the pure MSE-Technology with an ffmpeg/purejavascript solution:). Pure Adaptive Streaming:).

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make much sense. first of all HLS is not "free" in what sense? if your talking about mpeg2 patents, they have all expired. It is no less free that DASH. "pure" MSE/JS is just fmp4. the same fmp4 used by DASH, and optionally by HLS. DASH just adds an XML manifest file, and HLS an m3u8 manifest file.

Comment: Hello, thx for the infos but one objection to fMP4, when i us ogg/webm as Container it is no fMP4, HLS is the one that is not codec agnostic and Dash is, i know. This is why i have asked this Question. I search ffmpeg params which i can encoded every av-codec to use in dash with the right codec params and why i search examples or good links to sites that explain pure MSE/JS? One small thing ist the Overhead against dash-xml and javascript to use it (dash.js is very big), another thing is doing by learning and understandig mse:). But you are right in deep the answer on my questions cbe use dash

Comment: DASH is codec agnostic in theory, but in reality browsers only support AVC and VP9 and a very few HEVC. HLS supports AVC and HEVC. So preactilly, the only difference is VP9.

Comment: Just because you use “DASH like”segments (which are also HLS like, and CMAF like) doesn’t mean you need dash.js. You can make your own manifest and js.

Comment: Hello, yes cool but how i make my own manifest and the javascript? Do you know any goog sites or a code-example for the mse? It wil be great.

Comment: tell you how to make your own manifest? Just put a list of video segments into a text file. Just look and an m3u8 to see an example. Or just make the segment names predictable and don’t use a manifest. As for code W3c or MDN good.

Comment: This are all not the problems, the problems are that i need code examples or links. Dash and Hls are not the problem, too. The problem is that i can not generate webm-video-files that the mse accepted. Some videos from the web functioned or are not functioned and this is an encoder-problem. And i search help for encoding. I cannot wrong decoded webm put in an manifest, w the core of mse says. oh you are coder but you don't has aknowledgment from encoding an video fme. When i can encode correctly one-file-webm or an multiplebitratevidandaudoi, but i want to chunk with js to mse and don't use pr